# geolocation.getCurrentPosition fails at night -- How to provide own api key?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox, geolocation

This is a long question with probably a very short answer.

In my rails 5 application, I use this fairly basic JS implementation of the geolocation api to obtain the users location from the browser:

---

**UPDATE: Here is the whole script which uses the geocomplete plugin (https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/):**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%=ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']%>&language=<%=I18n.locale%>&libraries=places"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var geolocation = null;
    var lati  = null;
    var longi = null;

    //start by drawing a default map
    nogeoloc(); 
    function nogeoloc() {
      geo(lati,longi);
      console.log("no geolocation");
    }

    // check for geolocation support
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
      geolocation = window.navigator.geolocation;
    }
    if (geolocation) {
      geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, positionOptions);
    }
    var positionOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 10 * 1000, // 10 seconds
    };
    //in case of user permission, center the map at user' location
    function success(position) {
      lati  = position.coords.latitude;
      longi = position.coords.longitude;
      geo(lati,longi);
      console.log("geo data obtained");
    }
    // if denied permission or error, do nothing
    function error(positionError) {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(positionError);
    }

    // map drawing using the geocomplete library
    function geo(lati,longi){
      var myloc = false;
      if(lati && longi) {
        myloc = [lati, longi];
      }
      var options = {
        map: ".map_canvas",
        mapOptions: {
          scrollwheel: true
        },
        location: myloc ,
        details: "form",
        detailsAttribute: "geocompname",
        markerOptions: {
          draggable: true
        }
      };
      $("#geocomplete").geocomplete(options);
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var map = $("#geocomplete").geocomplete("map");
      var marker = $("#geocomplete").geocomplete("marker");

      if(lati && longi) {
        map.panTo({ lat: lati, lng: longi});
        marker.setPosition({ lat: lati, lng: longi});
        $("input[geocompname=lat]").val(lati);
        $("input[geocompname=lng]").val(longi);  
        geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat: lati, lng: longi}}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
              $("input[geocompname=formatted_address]").val(results[0].formatted_address);
            }
          }
        });
      }
      $("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function(event, latLng){
        $("input[geocompname=lat]").val(latLng.lat());
        $("input[geocompname=lng]").val(latLng.lng());
        map.panTo(latLng);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latLng }, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
              $("input[geocompname=formatted_address]").val(results[0].formatted_address);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

---

The *somehow funny* problem is that this implementation works fine during the day (I am based in Germany) but returns an error in both Firefox and Chrome at night :).

The error code returned in Firefox is: `{ code: 2, message: "Unknown error acquiring position" }`, Chrome prints more information: `message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403."`

Googling around, it turns out that 403 means that the usage limit of the provided api key was reached. This explains why my code works during the day and start failing at night :).

To test this, I opened the firefox config and inserted my own google api key into geo.wifi.uri and voilà it works.

Now my question(s):

1) This problem appears in the google's own browser (Chrome), even Mozilla's live example fails (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation), can one expect google/mozilla etc. to fix this issue soon by increasing the request limit?

2) The request is sent via the site visitor's browser. Is there a way to pass my own google key to the geolocation api, so that the browser uses it in the request instead of the default one?

3) The above code works fine in the chrome browser on my Samsung s6 phone, however it doesn't work on the same phone using the Samsung Internet browser. Any hints what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried geolocation.watchPosition just in case it works?

Comment: watchPosition doesn't work at the moment either, see here [Demo](https://www.audero.it/demo/geolocation-api-demo.html)
It was working two days ago. Also notice that the Firefox example doesn't work [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

Answer (score 1):

What does the geo function do? Are you getting the users location details (ex. city, address, etc)? The geolocation service shouldn't throw errors.. my guess is you're using Google Maps or Google Places APIs in conjunction. See here for more details: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/. I had a similar problem and adding a credit card to Google fixed my issue (they don't charge you it simply proves your not a bot and increases your limit.. but there is paid plans too)

Comment: I updated my question to include the whole script. Yes, I do use the Places and Geocoding APIs, but they go through my API Key and they work fine.

Also geolocation works fine if I let Firefox use my key. My question is how can I include my key on "your" browser if you are visiting my site.

Comment: You can also see my comment on @treecon answer. If the firefox live example doesn't work, then the problem is definitely in the geolocation service.